# How to compile OpenCV3 using MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, opencv3.0

I am trying to compile `OpenCV3` and put it into Qt project because Qt officially provides `MinGW` Version, so I didn't use `MinGW-w64`.

I enabled `ENABLE_CXX11` and disabled `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` in CMake.

Now the problem is `MinGW` does not contain `std::thread`.

I know the `mingw-std-threads` lib can fix it. but I don't want to modify OpenCV source code. Is there any other way to adding c++ thread feature to `MinGW`? or tell OpenCV using `pthread` by `CMake`?

BTW. I don't want use `Qt's MinGW` because I think using official `MinGW` to compile the lib shall be used in any version of Qt.

**Update:**

In OpenCV `detection_based_tracker.cpp`, there is a `CV_CXX11` Marco choice to the using `std thread` or the `pthread`. But I didn't see anywhere `define CV_CXX11`.

Is part of `detection_based_tracker.cpp` code:

```
#ifdef CV_CXX11
#define USE_STD_THREADS
#endif

#ifdef USE_STD_THREADS
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#else //USE_STD_THREADS
#include <pthread.h>
#endif //USE_STD_THREADS
```

My environment:

```
windows 7 64bit
cmake-3.10.1-win64-x64
opencv-3.4.0
gcc 6.3
```

What I tried:

1. install CMake and MinGW
2. disable `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` in `CMake-gui`
3. comment `#define USE_STD_THREADS` in `detection_based_tracker.cpp` line 48
4. configure and generate Makefile
5. Run `mingw32-make`

it's successfully compiled, but I have to modify OpenCV source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the right version of MinGW, namely MinGW-w64, most toolchains builds have the modern threading features available.

You can e.g. use [the installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) or install it through [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried MinGW-w64 and it works, But I need to add the OpenCV into official Qt which bases on MinGW32, So I have to use the MinGW32.

Comment: Recent Official Qt builds should be using a MinGW-w64 based distribution of GCC. I'm not entirely sure they properly enable c++ threads though. You can check by running "gcc -v" and checking if the threading model is "posix". This should mean, on GCC versions >= 4.9 that C++11 threads are available.